# Why doesn't Android view chain spread in a fragment with constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

The XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".FragmentCounter">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:text="@string/plus"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/minus"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/count" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="@string/minus"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/plus"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/count" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/zero"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/counter_text"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iWRz.jpg

What it shows in Android Studio's layout design view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsNic.png

I created it in design view, first I added the minimum necessary constraints and then created the chain by selecting the two views, left click -> chains -> add horizontal chain. Then I changed the horizontal chain style to "spread".

I tried doing the same thing outside the fragment (in activity) and it worked, so you can't make chains in fragments?

Comment: Post the code you use to create the layout in the fragment. Are you specifying a parent in the inflation for the layout?

Comment: ConstraintLayout chains has nothing to do with Activities or Fragments.

Comment: I don't think `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"` looks right. Remove it and check what it does. `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"` should do the work. Other than that, I don't see anything wrong with your code.